# Swift 5 Xcode 11 Как исправить код, чтобы при втором и более нажатии кнопка писала в консоль hi?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI

var ibr : Bool = false
var trys = 0
func mybut() {
    if trys >= 1 {
        ibr = true
        if ibr {
            print("hi")
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var buttonName = "gwg"
    var body: some View {
        Button(buttonName){
            mybut()
            }
        }
        
    }


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: вы меняете условие до его проверки в первое нажатие, а нужно после

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func mybut(trys: Int) {
    if trys >= 1 {
        print("hi")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var buttonName = "gwg"
    @State var trys = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(buttonName){
            mybut(trys: trys)
            trys += 1
        }
    }
    
}
```